# Resize UILabel width in ios9

Tags: ios, uilabel, ios9

I have created a label in storyboard with unchecked auto layout. 
I tried to change the y coordinate of the label, it was display nicely in iOS 8.4 but when i run in iOS 9 it still stick at original place didn't change the position that i wanted.

For example the label is at 10 originally but I want change it to 20.

```
dateLbl.frame=CGRectMake(0,20,100,40);
```

Comment: did you use constraint with your label ?

Comment: @Armanoide i don't think so. because i'm not using autolayout on that

Comment: your code is fine , can u add some additional code

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik     NSString *description=@"here the string that i want to check the size" CGSize expectedSize = [description boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin) attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"STHeitiTC-Medium" size:17.f]} context:nil].size;
articleTitleLbl.frame = CGRectMake(15, 12, articleTitleLbl.frame.size.width, expectedSize.height+6);